# Texturing problem looks like broken image

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

i am having a problem right now, i add some image for floor but when i was trying to rendering, i am taking this view. How can i fix this ? 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have two identical shapes and polygons in exactly the same places. One set of polygons has the texture and the other doesn't. Double-check this by right-click selecting anything in that space. Then press <kbd>M</kbd> and <kbd>2</kbd> moving whatever was selected to Layer 2. Whatever geometry stays behind will tell you which object, textured or not, you selected.

<kbd>X</kbd> Delete what's not needed. If what you needed was moved to the second Layer, press <kbd>2</kbd> along the number row (not numpad) and <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> select it and press <kbd>M</kbd> and <kbd>1</kbd> to move it to the first layer.

Blender Render and Cycles do not play well with sheets of polygons in identical locations.